# How to join a specific column of List<DataRow> with a comma?

Tags: c#

Instead of using **foreach** or **for** to find the last or first element to ignore the comma. I am sure there must be a way to easily concatenate a specific column of a list of **DataRows**.

Here what I have tried

```
List<DataRow> rows;

string forms = rows.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, row) => current + row[1] + ", ");
```

Output : A, B, C, D,

```
string forms = rows.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, row) => current + ", " + row[1]);
```

Output : ,A, B, C, D

Also tried this suggestion :

```
string forms = string.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(rows.ToArray(), i => i.ToString()));
```

Output: System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow<>

What is wanted:

Output A, B, C, D

Comment: I'm curious whats wrong with option 1, then removing the last character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot to get `row[1]`, if you do `row.ToString()` the output is the class name `DataRow`

```
string forms = string.Join(", ", rows.Select(row => row[1].ToString()).ToArray());
```

if you are on .NET > 4 you can skip the `.ToArray()` because there is an IEnumerable overload

```
string forms = string.Join(", ", rows.Select(row => row[1].ToString()));
```

or with ConvertAll

```
string forms = string.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(rows.ToArray(), i => i[1].ToString()));
```

A note: `Aggregate` throw System.InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains no elements" if no elements, instead `String.Join` return empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
string forms = rows.Select(row => row[1])
                   .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

This transforms into values first and concatenates them. It's easier in two steps.

Comment: I'd go with `string.Join()` rather than `Aggregate()`, but `Select()` is obviously the way to do this.